# How to arrange a list

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to bring a 'Bewertung' and a 'Leistung' for same Person to one line, but if the 'Bewertung' and the 'Leistung' is not for same Person I have to split it. See example. Is there a way for SQL to do this?

[image]

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and things in german doesnt help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select sip, namen, lstnamen,
       sum(Bewertung), sum(Leistung)
from t
group by sip, namen, lstnamen;
```

Comment: That's so simple, but it works exactly so, how I was looking for. I didn't see the forest for the trees (embarrassing!)